# I have a vmlinux which is build using arm cross compiler. Can I use virtual box to boot this vmlinux?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualbox

I want to crash the vmlinux I have and then debug it. But I do not have arm processor. Can I use virtual box to boot this vmlinux and then I can use debugfs interface to make my vmlinux crash?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to crash the vmlinux I have and then debug it. But I do not
>   have arm processor. Can I use virtual box to boot this vmlinux and
>   then I can use debugfs interface to make my vmlinux crash?

virtual box does not emulate the processor, you need something like qemu to do such stuff, refer following links for more info on qemu

[1] https://www.qemu.org/

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Virtual_ARM_Linux_environment

[3] https://gist.github.com/Liryna/10710751